# UX portfolio guidelines

Tags: guidelines, ux-designer, portfolio

I have a simple question for you...

I would like to create an UX portfolio, but I don not have any idea where to start. I already have a Front-End/Web Designer portfolio, but I would like to include my UX projects.

Basically I am not sure what should I write there. I mean, if someone who is interested to hire me lands on one of my UX project, what does he/she expect to see on it?.

I have been researching on the internet and basically, every UX portfolio is different and some of them are BLOCK OF TEXT - boring!. So, I didn't have luck to find a good guideline or example to follow.

So them, I wonder if you could give me a guidelines to follow in order to have a tidy an eye appeal UX portfolio please.

It is my Front-End/Web Designer portfolio [www.andresarigon.com](http://www.andresarigon.com) as you can see I could make a lot of visual recourse if it is necessary.

Thanks,

Comment: Kind suggestion: Make sure the top full-screen image stops exactly at the bottom of the browser screen. At the moment, at least on Safari, it runs the height of your top menu bar too far, below the bottom screen edge.

Comment: I need to check it on Safari. I cannot see any problem on Chrome, Firefox, IE. Thanks

Comment: Hi again I am checking it right now on a desktop Mac and I can't find any error. Would you mind to tell me which version of Safari are you using and also if are using mobile, desktop or laptop please?

Comment: Checked from my imac on safari in full screen and could not find a visual error. Also in smaller window everything looks good on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are allready showcasing Front-End and Webdesign work which is pretty visual, i would showcase the process and the "behind the scenes" when it comes to the UX.

Show the client how you work and have worked in the past, how you interact with developers and stakeholders, what goals you were able to achieve (for example conversion rates, less support tickets for a different task etc.)

You dont need to write all this stuff up since its indeed pretty boring and people dont realy like to read on the web, take small pieces of text and combine them with visuals that show off your way of working.

Comment: I think It is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: **Stand out!** Make a one page portfolio/CV that's extremely easy to read & understand sprinkled with great design that asks for more.

Treat it as a full page ad and write the texts as if your copywriting. Read up on copywriting if you need to.

(You have a great website!)

Comment: I can't i have less than 15 rep